# How to fetch the list of generated path coordinates on a Google Map painted in the Qt window?

Tags: qt, google-maps

The way to generate a path between two coordinates is shown here: http://apidocs.meego.com/1.2-preview/qtmobility/qgeoroutingmanager.html

Now how to get the list of all the coordinates lying on the generated path (through QGeoRoutingManager) on the Qt widget containing the map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This class calculates the routes:
1. http://apidocs.meego.com/1.2-preview/qtmobility/qgeoroutingmanager.html

The concerned function in the above class returns the: http://apidocs.meego.com/git-tip/qtmobility.orig/qgeoroutereply.html

We need to find all the coordinates on the route, so that the route can be displayed:
1. "QGeoRouteReply" has a member routes (): http://apidocs.meego.com/1.2-preview/qtmobility/qgeoroutereply.html#routes which returns "QList"

"QGeoRoute" class has a function "path" which returns all the coordinates of the path: http://apidocs.meego.com/1.2-preview/qtmobility/qgeoroute.html#path

We can use those coordinates through "QPainter" class to draw lines on the map.

***EDIT***:

All these explanations are w.r.t NOKIA's OVI maps. QtMobility doesn't support Google maps. :(